# Package names for Phone app on Huawei phones

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

I am developing android app and want to launch Phone app from one of my dashboard screen. But Phone app is merged with contacts app, and when I open it opening contacts app by default,instead it should  open Phone app. I have set ,
 intent.setClassName( "com.android.contacts", "com.android.contacts.activities.DialtactsActivity") and starting activity, but its opening contacts screen instead of phone.

Can anyone suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I think in most (if not all) Huawei devices the package responsible for the phone app is `com.android.phone`

From within an activity you can use the following intent to open the dialer:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL); 
startActivity(intent);
```